# 2 identical folders, file names the same but different file size. I want smallest version only

Tags: batch-file, recursion, size

I have 2 folder structures with many sub directories with only .ofr files in them. Both have identical layout and sub directory names with identical amounts of files and file names but compressed differently. Some files in folder 1 will be smaller, others larger than in folder 2.

I would love to be able to have a batch file to scan each file and move the smallest over the largest to achieve a folder with only the smallest version of each file in it.

In many cases, the size difference is a matter of bytes but overall at 3gb, it will make some difference.

Example folder 1 is SOUNDS_MC and folder 2 is SOUNDS_MCX.

Comment: Generally, the questions without any effort put into solving them are closed, but this one seems easy.

Comment: That's not very helpfull....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple batch file that works on file names without `!` in names.

```dos
@echo off
set "FOLDER1=c:\SOUNDS_MC"
set "FOLDER2=d:\SOUNDS_MCX"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /r "%FOLDER1%" %%a in (*) do (
    set "otherFile=%%a" & set "otherFile=!otherFile:%FOLDER1%=%FOLDER2%!"
    for %%b in ("!otherFile!*") do if "%%~nxb" == "%%~nxa" (
        if %%~zb GTR %%~za copy/b "%%a" "%%b" >nul & echo A-^>B: "%%a"
        if %%~zb LSS %%~za copy/b "%%b" "%%a" >nul & echo B-^>A: "%%b"
    )
)
pause & exit
```

If both folders are on the same drive you can use NTFS hardlinking via `fsutil` (use google).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this shortly :)

Comment: How can I modify this so that it still compares same filenames in 2 folders but file extension can be different. Hence comparing to different file types sharing same name?

Comment: Use `set "otherFile=%%~dpna.*"` instead of `set "otherFile=%%a"` and remove `if "%%~nxb" == "%%~nxa"` I guess.

Comment: This solution does NOT work!! This modification seems to copy smallest file but rename extension........The aim is to compare all files in both folders, like before, keeping only the smallest of any file regardless of the extension. Maybe if I explain what i am doing?] Compressing wav files with various programs to individual folders. i.e. I have a WV folder containing wavpack conversions, extension .wv, optimfrog with extension .ofr....therefore example folder WV has 50 files, and Optimfrog 50 files.

Comment: I need to compare each file and only keep the smallest, retaining it's filename and extension, removing larger file irrelevent of extension.  I hope this clarifies the question. Thank you for your assistance to date...

Comment: Well, indeed, I don't understand what you want to do now. It's better to ask a new question with an example of file/folder structure and the desired result.

Comment: OK done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459382/2-folders-containing-same-quantity-of-files-same-file-names-but-different-file-s